# Delay on image switch javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do so when a button is pressed, it changes my image after a second.

This is what i have so far

```
setTimeout(function hit2() {
    document.getElementById("game1").src = "http://i.imgur.com/bzWhdPV.png";
}
}, 10);
```

When i press the button, nothing happens.
Can anyone help me out with this, and explain to me why this is not working.

Comment: Also the "10" in ms is a mistake. It is now set to 1000.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code for the button too?

Comment: got two "}" at the end where one is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your syntax is incorrect

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("game1").src = "http://i.imgur.com/bzWhdPV.png";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: it is not working he is not asking how to make the time longer.

Comment: if you would look more carefully you will notice that I fixed is syntax.. he was the one that noted the 10 to 1000 difference in the first comment

Comment: please be more careful before downvoting

Comment: i didnt down grade it.. but yes noticed it now

Comment: That's why snippet-only answers aren't always the most helpful. It's often easy to overlook details about it when an explanation isn't paired with it.